# How to clear the log in ui5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5

I am logging stuff in  my sapui5 application.

At some point I get all logs logged so far with[`getLogEntries()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.log.html#.getLogEntries) and persist them. Now can I somehow DELETE those logs from the `jQuery.sap.log`to not get them again when I `getLogEntries()` again?

Those are only the symptoms. The problem Root is that I do not have a uniqe key for those objects. But for the persistation I have to have a UID.

Comment: Just do not invoke `getLogEntries` again...

Comment: @Rayon I have to do so.. And I can not refresh the page to clear the log..

Comment: You are calling a function and you do not want to happen what is happening in handler...

Answer (score 1):

Just some ideas ;)

Idea 1:
I am not exactly sure what you real problem is but to accomplish you goal you can execute getLogEntries, save for example the amount of logged items or the item itself. If you want to log again you can just iterate until that position in order to cut the previous entries.

Idea 2:
On the other hand if its non productive code you can extend the existing Logger. Its defined in jQuery.sap.global. Load the dbg sources to get the ununglified version. Should be defined starting at line ~800.

Idea 3:
Extend the existing logger, the idea is to add additional code so that you don't need to change the existing logger but you register something like an after callback. That way you can add custom code.

```
jQuery.sap.log.oldDebug = jQuery.sap.log.debug
jQuery.sap.log.debug = function(,,){jQuery.sap.log.oldDebug(,,); /* Custom Code like adding own log to some array*/ }
jQuery.sap.log.getCustom = function() {/* get from custom array */}
jQuery.sap.log.reset = function() {/* delete all entrys in array */}
```

So it heavily depends on your usecase. Each solution has advantages and disadvantages. But have a look at the source, thats quiet helpful

Comment: I will make changes on the logger, since I want to get the log if an error/fatal occours. The thing is that I do not want to change the signature because I need the standart as fallback. But Thanks for your Inputs, I will tell the solution when I am done!

Comment: Alright! just had another idea... If its useful for other too, you may can make a pullRequest on github to openUi5 with a new delete method

Comment: I think more of a flag like `read` or a key so that you know which logs are allready handeld.